# how to avoid Google sheets + google forms adding a row and breaking formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, google-forms

I noticed one thing that is due to how google Forms works. In the same workbook I have a sheet called Test which is a form response sheet from a linked google forms and another sheet called pedidos, which is a sheet where I query data from test so I can add formulas on to that sheet.  This script runs daily so I can have clean daily data on these sheets as the data is only useful on the day of.

I have on the pedidos sheet a query formula `=QUERY(Test!A2:X100)` on b2 cell. When I run this script on the pedidos sheet, and google forms runs again, the formula in pedidos sheet changes to `=QUERY(Test!A3:X100)`, but data in test sheet keeps starting on `Test!a2`. This I assume is because in the test sheet when google forms adds data it adds a row and that behavior is reflecting on the pedidos sheet, in so altering formulas on pedidos sheet.

Is there a way I can avoid this happening so it doesn't break the formula? Can I add something to this script that would keep the `=QUERY(Test!A2:X100)` intact?

```
function sendExcelAndDeleteRows() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // 
  var emailAddress = "###"; // 
  var subject = "Excel Sheet - Pedidos";
  var message = "Please find attached the Excel sheet for Pedidos.";

  // Export Pedidos sheet to Excel format
  var pedidosSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Pedidos");
  var pedidosDataRange = pedidosSheet.getDataRange();
  var pedidosValues = pedidosDataRange.getValues();
  var pedidosHeader = pedidosValues[0];
  var pedidosNewRange = pedidosSheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, pedidosHeader.length - 1);
  pedidosNewRange.setValues([pedidosHeader.slice(1)]);

  var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var pedidosFileName = "Pedidos_" + dateToday + ".xlsx";
  var pedidosFile = DriveApp.createFile(pedidosFileName, pedidosDataRange.getValues(), MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [pedidosFile]});

  // Delete rows after row 1 in Test sheet
  var testSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Test");
  testSheet.deleteRows(2, testSheet.getLastRow() - 1);

  // Get the last rows in the data range of Pedidos sheet
  var lastColumn = pedidosDataRange.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = pedidosDataRange.getLastRow();

  // Clear range after column B & row 2
  pedidosSheet.getRange(2,3,lastRow,lastColumn).clearContent()
  
  // Delete the temporary file
  pedidosFile.setTrashed(true);
}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendExcelAndDeleteRows')
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
    .atHour(20)
    .nearMinute(30)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide sample data for sheet "Test" (the sheet linked to the Form).  The script performs tasks that are hard to understand/rationalise (e.g. header row on Pedidos, deletion of rows on Pedidos, deletion of rows on "Test", numer of rows of data on "Test"). The combined effect on the formula in B2 of Pedidos is speculation without knowing the data rows that remain after the script has run.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular scenario you can just hard-code the range `A2:X100` via using indirect() in place of your current query formula:

```js
=indirect("Test!A2:X100")
```

Comment: Any thoughts (other than the vagaries of life) on _why_ it happens? It **is** odd, don't you think.

Comment: Its actually a general odd scenario that happens within forms+sheets responses world. lets say the formula is pointing to the range A2:X100 of the form responses tab→now the OP script cleared the data→Next day when fresh response(s) are filled, google form adds a new row to the response tab for each new response→all these new rows are added above row_2→so the formula pointing to the range A2:X100 will keep shifting downside alike A3(when one response comes) then again changes to A4 (when another response comes in) and so on.. so harcoding it with indirect() will fix it